# Identical entities generating different ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I ensure that EF generates the same Id for the same occurence of an object?

E.g. if I have a class like:

```
class Foo{
    ICollection<Bar> Bar1;
    ICollection<Bar> Bar2;
}
```

If I create a new entity `Foo` and add a single instance of `Bar` (no id set) to both `Bar1` and `Bar2` - will it use the same Id for both or create a new one each time? E.g.:

```
var bar = new Bar();
var foo = new Foo{
   Bar1 = new List<Bar>(){ bar };
   Bar2 = new List<Bar>(){ bar };
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Will `Bar1` and `Bar2` contain the same record `bar` with the same id?

UPDATE: What if I have two instances that are the same with respect to `Equals` and hash code?

```
var first = new Bar();
var second = new Bar();   /// first.equals(second )
var foo = new Foo{
   Bar1 = new List<Bar>(){ first };
   Bar2 = new List<Bar>(){ second };
}
```

or does EF not check for equals?

Comment: It seems like it would be faster for you to just try it yourself, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Entity Framework will create one record for `foo` and one record for `bar` in the database. Since both lists contain the same instance of `Bar` the respective database entries will point to the same record.

Comment: Thanks! What if there are two instances that are `Equal`? See update.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are equal: two DIFFERENT instances=two records in the database. The only way to change this would be to have a trigger in your database that merges rows based on equal column values.

Comment: EF doesn't care about equality. It only cares about sameness (is that a word?) I.e. the same instance will lead to one record, different instances that are equal (as in Equals() == true) will lead to multiple records.